# How to set item of tuple recived by linq

Tags: c#, linq, tuples

I have list of tuples. I need to get one of this tuples using linq and change item2 of it.
I tried to do it straightforward like that:

```
            Tuples.First(s => s.Item1 == i).Item += value;
```

but it didn't compile.
I also tried to do it so:

```
        (int, int) tuple = Tuples.First(s => s.Item1 == i);
        tuple.Item2 += value;
```

but tuple doesn't work as a reference variable

So, how should it be done?

Comment: `tuple = (tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2 + value);` tuples are *immutable*, you can't change them, but can recreate

Comment: Because tuple is `struct` and value type, you should create a new instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are *immutable*; you can't *change* existing tuple, but you can *create a new* one:

```
    (int, int) tuple = Tuples.First(s => s.Item1 == i);

    tuple = (tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2 + value);
```

Or

```
    (int, int) tuple = Tuples
      .Select(s => (s.Item1, s.Item2 + value)) 
      .First(s => s.Item1 == i);
```

Comment: Value tuples are actually mutable structs.

Comment: `Tuple<T1, T2>` are immutable class:  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,25b439d8dd9b7594 here we have `private readonly T1 m_Item1;` and `private readonly T1 m_Item2;` `ValueTuple` is a mutable struct

Comment: Yes, but code is definitely not about `Tuple` class but about value tuples otherwise `(int, int) tuple = Tuples.First(s => s.Item1 == i);` will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.item1?view=netcore-3.1), `tuple.Item1` only has a getter which means it is a read-only property.

You either need to create a new tuple with one changed value and the rest left the same, or create a class to use instead of that tuple which will have mutable properties.

Answer (score 0):

If `Tuples` is an array you can modify value this way (as with any other mutable struct):

```
var Tuples = new[] {(0, 0)};
ref var t = ref Tuples[0]; // find needed index somehow
t.Item1 += 1;
Console.WriteLine(Tuples[0].Item1); // prints 1
```